# FirebaseMessagingService: No notifications when phone is sleeping

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FirebaseMessagingService. I am sending some notifications with the server. However, these notifications do not come when the phone's screen is turned off for a while, or when it sleeps. When I open the phone's screen or run the application, these notifications begin to appear collectively. Dozens of notifications pile up at once. In order for this not to happen, what should I do to make the notifications always come?

I am using default codes.

Regards

```
    <service
        android:name="com.myapp.services.sFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Doze Mode Alarm Service:

```
public class WOnTrackerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt, WOnTrackerFirebaseMessagingService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //for 1 mint 1*60*1000
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                1*60*1000, pintent);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at these:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message
2. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: I updated my code. I added an onReceive but this code doesn't even give a logchat.

Answer (score 0):

To make firebase library to call your `onMessageReceived()` in the following cases

- App in foreground
- App in background
- App has been killed

You must not use the `notification` property as seen here:

```
{
   "to": "/topics/journal",
   "notification": {
   "title" : "title",
   "text": "data!",
   "icon": "ic_notification"
    }
}
```

But instead, bundle it as a data FCM - which lets the device handle it directly.

```
{
  "to": "/topics/dev_journal",
   "data": {
       "text":"text",
       "title":"",
       "line1":"Journal",
       "line2":"some data"
   }
}
```

The message is sent in the argument `RemoteMessage` along with your data object as `Map<String, String>` of which you can manage within your app's `onMessageReceived()`.

Answer (score 0):

If messages should appear when the device is in the doze mode, the messages must have set a high priority. Messages sent with 'normal' priority don't come when your phone is in doze mode. Here is a possible solution that worked for me:

```
private void forwardMessageToFCM(String notificationMessage, boolean highPriority) {
    Message message;
    if (highPriority) {
        message = createFCMMessageWithHighPriority(notificationMessage + APPEND_FCM_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        message = createFCMMessageWithNormalPriority(notificationMessage + APPEND_FCM_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    try {
        firebaseMessaging.send(message);
        printInfo("Sent message to FCM: " + notificationMessage);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
        printException(e);
        return;
    }
}

private Message createFCMMessageWithNormalPriority(String notificationMessage) {
    return Message.builder().setNotification(createFCMNotification(notificationMessage)).setToken(registrationToken)
            .setAndroidConfig(createAndroidConfigWithNormalMessagePriority()).build();
}

private Message createFCMMessageWithHighPriority(String notificationMessage) {
    return Message.builder().setNotification(createFCMNotification(notificationMessage)).setToken(registrationToken)
            .setAndroidConfig(createAndroidConfigWithHighMessagePriority()).build();
}

private AndroidConfig createAndroidConfigWithHighMessagePriority() {
    return createAndroidConfigWithPriority(Priority.HIGH);
}

private AndroidConfig createAndroidConfigWithNormalMessagePriority() {
    return createAndroidConfigWithPriority(Priority.NORMAL);
}

private AndroidConfig createAndroidConfigWithPriority(Priority priority) {
    return AndroidConfig.builder().setPriority(priority).build();
}

private Notification createFCMNotification(String notificationMessage) {
    return Notification.builder().setBody(notificationMessage).setTitle(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TITLE).build();
}
```

Use createFCMMessageWithHighPriority-method in order to create a notification message with high priority. But according to doc, this should only used for important messages.
Further info about priorities: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message