# AlarmManager is not calling onReceive

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

I opened this topic because I had problems with application notifications; [FirebaseMessagingService: No notifications when phone is sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025184/firebasemessagingservice-no-notifications-when-phone-is-sleeping)
I'm using AlarmManager in my project to run it in 1 minute, but when I wanted to print a log, I realized that it wasn't working correctly. Broadcast does not respond in any way. What is the reason?

Regards

```
public class WOnTrackerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt, WOnTrackerFirebaseMessagingService.class);

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //for 1 mint 1*60*1000
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                1*60*1000, pintent);

    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
Permission: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <receiver android:name="com.myproject.receivers.WOnTrackerReceiver">
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `AlarmManager` to get repeating alarms at that rate. Generally speaking 2 minutes is an absolute minimum, and many manufacturers have even stricter limitations.

You should use a `Handler` and `postDelayed()` if you need to run code at that frequency.

Also, `setRepeating()` does not reliably deliver on time. There are other methods of `AlarmManager` that you can use to get more accurate timing. But as I said, not with a frequency under 2 minutes.

Also, you asked why the `AlarmManager` is not calling your `BroadcastReceiver`, but the code snippet you've posted uses `AlarmManager` to start a `Service` (`WOnTrackerFirebaseMessagingService`) every minute, not call your  `BroadcastReceiver`. Are you confused?

Comment: I can set the frequency cap to a more convenient time. But when I want to run this code, no information appears in logchat. So I suspect this code is not working. I thought I had all the settings right but the problem I'm having here is that onReceive does not return any logchat.

Comment: When do you expect `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` to be called? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: I want this to run in the background every 30 minutes. Do we need a trigger for broadcaststreceiver to work? For example, we use broadcastreceiver to capture incoming sms. We weren't using any code to trigger this.

Comment: Yes, you will need something to call your `BroadcastReceiver`. When you set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to capture incoming SMS, you have specified the trigger in an `<intent-filter>`. You have an `<intent-filter>` for this `BroadcastReceiver`, but it only gets called on device boot. So unless your device boots, you won't see `onReceive()` being called.

Comment: Then how can I use it? I want this alarm to go off once every 30 minutes.

Comment: I'm confused. You are using the `BroadcastReceiver` to schedule an `AlarmManager` trigger to start a `Service`. This is fine. All you need to do is trigger the `BroadcastReceiver` once yourself. Create an `Intent` for the `BroadcastReceiver` and call `sendBroadcast()`. Where/when do you want to start this? I assume you want to start this from an `Activity`.

Comment: I can't find how to trigger the WOnTrackerReceiver.java file.

Comment: Do you have an `Activity` to start all of this?